# How to merge duplicated keys in list in vectors in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

My function return for me like this:

```
 ([:common/to "To" "client/pages/individual_profile.cljs"]
 [:common/to "To" "client/component/edit_experience_dialog.cljs"]
 [:search/advanced-size-b "6 - 50" "client/pages/search/search_conditions.cljs"]
 [:type "Type" "re_frame/signup.cljs"]
 [:type "Type" "re_frame/multiple_jurisdictions.cljs"])
```

If you can see, I have a duplicated keys in first place in vector like `:common/to` and `:type`
and I need change this to:

```
([:common/to "To" "client/pages/individual_profile.cljs" "client/component/edit_experience_dialog.cljs"]
[:search/advanced-size-b "6 - 50" "client/pages/search/search_conditions.cljs"]
[:type "Type" "re_frame/signup.cljs" "re_frame/multiple_jurisdictions.cljs"])
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual when you have a list of things that you want to correlate by some property, it's a good idea to instead have a map, keyed by that property. Then you will find there are loads of existing tools that easily do what you wanted. In this case, if your data were shaped "right" to begin with, `(apply merge-with into ms)` would be all you needed.

```
(def input '([:common/to "To" "client/pages/individual_profile.cljs"]
 [:common/to "To" "client/component/edit_experience_dialog.cljs"]
 [:search/advanced-size-b "6 - 50" "client/pages/search/search_conditions.cljs"]
 [:type "Type" "re_frame/signup.cljs"]
 [:type "Type" "re_frame/multiple_jurisdictions.cljs"]))

(apply merge-with into
       (for [[k label & vs] input]
         {[k label] (vec vs)}))
; => {[:common/to "To"] ["client/pages/individual_profile.cljs" "client/component/edit_experience_dialog.cljs"], 
      [:search/advanced-size-b "6 - 50"] ["client/pages/search/search_conditions.cljs"], 
      [:type "Type"] ["re_frame/signup.cljs" "re_frame/multiple_jurisdictions.cljs"]}
```